# Completely uninstall xampp if not installed from apt-get

Tags: uninstall, xampp

I've downloaded XAMPP from their website.
And then manually installed it from my home directory and it is installed in /opt/lampp

I've made tons of changes and I don't remember how to revert back to it's default state, so I need a fresh new clean install.

Besides doing `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop` and  `sudo rm -R /opt/lampp`.
Is there anything else that I should delete? Maybe from files that it might used from home directory?

Apart from that. Does doing above completely remove XAMPP from my system?

Comment: have you looked in your home directory if you have any file called uninstall? some programs when source-installed comes with a uninstall script

Comment: Direct home? I've run `ls -la ~ | grep install`. Got nothing

Comment: i meant inside the folder of the app in your home, if you have one

Comment: nope. can't find any of *.xampp* folder/file either. Although, when i ran `grep -l -r xampp ~/`. It returns quite alot of directory especially *.local/share* and *.cache/*. Not sure if safe or should delete.

Answer (score 19):

This should remove XAMPP completely as they provide the uninstaller files in `/opt/lampp/`

```
 sudo chmod +x /opt/lampp/uninstall
 sudo /opt/lampp/uninstall
```

Then you can make sure the unistallation is complete by doing user318149's answer above. cheers

Answer (score 4):

`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop`, `sudo rm -rf /opt/lampp` and `rm -rf ~/.lampp` (Log files) did it for me. There is no Lampp/Xampp related configs/logs in ~/.cache or ~/.local/share

Answer (score 3):

This is the full code to uninstall lampp..

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
sudo chmod +x /opt/lampp/uninstall
sudo /opt/lampp/uninstall
sudo rm -R /opt/lampp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall Xampp in ubuntu by going to terminal: Ctrl + Alt + T then type:

```
cd /opt/lampp
sudo ./uninstall
```

then you get the xampp uninstaller and you can uninstall xampp.
but, there are some leftover file in the lampp folder to remove it just type in terminal:

```
sudo rm -r /opt/lampp
```

Now xampp is removed completely.

Answer (score 0):

Lampp actually have an uninstaller files in `/opt/lampp/`named `unintaller`. Just change the mode using this command

- `cd /opt/lampp/` to enter the directory
- `sudo chmod +x uninstaller` to change it into executable file
- `./uninstaller` to run the unistaller file

Answer (score 0):

The default directory for XAMPP is “opt/lampp”.

Open the terminal and type

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop
```

after this type

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/lampp
```